# Angular2 Material SnackBar integration problems

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2, snackbar

I am trying to integrate [Material Snackbar](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/snack-bar/README.md) in my angular2 app.

I have already succesfully integrated `ProgressBar` from the same library successfully but running into errors with SnackBar.

Here's how I am integrating `SnackBar`

**(relevant) app.module.ts**:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    CoreModule,
    UsersModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
],
```

**(relevant) app.component.ts:**

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private router: Router,
            private snackBar: MdSnackBar,
            private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
}

// this method is bound to a simple button in template
showSnack() {
    this.snackBar.open("Showing Snack", "Yayyy!");
}
```

Upon clicking that `showSnack` button, I get this error:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: view.animationContext.getAnimationPlayers is not a function

A more detailed stacktrace: 
[image]

Comment: It works for me https://plnkr.co/edit/FOIyGX0cxLVCuBVaoUvg?p=preview  I have also tried it on local machine

Comment: Yes, works in plunker but not locally. Do you think it might have something to do with package versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but it was an issue with package versions.

This problem was on Material `2.0.0-alpha.11-3` while my angular is on `2.2.0`.

**Updating material library to `2.0.0-beta.1` fixed my problem.**